# React Higher Order Component explained with Context API example

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, higher-order-components, react-context

I am trying to understand an example of using high order components with context api, used [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jpy76nm1v).

Since, I am pretty new to react and functional programming, I don't understand how are things actually working here. We are sending a function to the function `withUser`, that returns another function which receives the `props`.

```
function withUser(Component) {
  return function ConnectedComponent(props) {
    return (
      <UserContext.Consumer>
        {user => <Component {...props} user={user} />}
      </UserContext.Consumer>
    );
  };
}
```

So, when we are creating `UserAvatar` we are passing the function that receives the `props`, and returns `img`.

```
const UserAvatar = withUser(({ user, size }) => (
  <img
    className={`user-avatar ${size || ""}`}
    alt="user avatar"
    src={user.avatar}
  />
));
```

So, basically after this we can imagine `UserAvatar` to be:

```
const UserAvatar = props => {
        return (
          <UserContext.Consumer>
            {user => <Component {...props} user={user} />}
          </UserContext.Consumer>
        );
      };
```

Where `Component` is:

```
({ user, size }) => (
      <img
        className={`user-avatar ${size || ""}`}
        alt="user avatar"
        src={user.avatar}
      />
    )
```

I hope this is right so far, but then what I don't understand is this line:

```
{user => <Component {...props} user={user} />}
```

Why do we need to make this as a function and not just return the component, when we have the `props` already and are passing the `user` to the `UserAvatar` component here down from the `UserStats` component?

```
const UserStats = () => (
  <UserContext.Consumer>
    {user => (
      <div className="user-stats">
        <div>
          <UserAvatar user={user} />
          {user.name}
        </div>
        <div className="stats">
          <div>{user.followers} Followers</div>
          <div>Following {user.following}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )}
  </UserContext.Consumer>
);
```

Comment: The UserAvatar is the parent component. UserStats does not know UserAvatar exist. UserAvatar needs to know what components are passed up so it can render the children props. The props are passed to UserAvatar because it is the control module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way is to describe an analogous concept: the function decorator.

```
// Start with a function, any function.
let add = (a, b) => a + b;
```

But now we want to add logging for the arguments and return:

```
let addWithLogging = (a, b) => {
  console.log("Args are ", a, b);
  const result = a + b;
  console.log("Result is ", result);
  return result;
}
```

Barf. Our simple one line function is now complicated by a bunch of stuff that is completely incidental to adding two numbers. If most of our functions are simple, and we want to add logging to all of them, back-of-the-envelope calculation is that our codebase is going to double. Double barf.

But wait, this is JavaScript, we have higher order functions and can extract a decorator:

```
// Here we take a function f and wrap it. We'll return a function that will
// collect the arguments, log them, perform f on them, log the result, and
// then finally return that result to the caller.
const withLogging = f => (...args) => {
  console.log("Args are ", ...args);
  const result = f(...args);
  console.log("Result is ", result);
  return result;
};

addWithLogging = withLogging(add);
```

React uses this same idea with higher order components, you have a component that needs some additional functionality (frequently state and/or making AJAX calls). You don't want to complicate your nice simple testable pure functional component with all that, so you use a higher order component instead. Much like the logging decorator above, the higher order component in your example takes a component as argument, and returns an anonymous pure functional component that actually receives the props and renders the passed in component wrapped in a UserContext component.

You *could* just make the UserContext component part of the JSX returned by the other component:

```
const UserAvatar = ({ user, size }) => (
  <UserContext.Consumer>
    <img
      className={`user-avatar ${size || ""}`}
      alt="user avatar"
      src={user.avatar}
    />
  </UserContext.Consumer>
);
```

But now, just like in the logging example, you're repeating the boilerplate in every component that needs it.

In regards to the specific line you're referencing, you arguably don't need a function there because as far as I can tell `user` is already in `props` when the component is rendered. For reference, here's the [compiled JSX](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdxlAFgVQM4FMBOAggBQDCcAtgA4K5hQCUiA3gFCKL65Qj5KiRYCROTBhc0XABNy1WvWJV8cKtiZsOHLjz6Ji7TRwA8OAqKi4AHlAB0o7CAoEAfAcMdmIPPkQBeZ4hGsjTi9Cw2EUoq2AC-iF4Evp7ecQD0zjFumkappvjmVrb2ji5ZDADcBjGVmawC0PBIqBh5AEJklCF0jCwG2rz84A3CouKSMp3yUIrKqupZ_br67oF5BdZ2CA5O-K4rxsFT4ZGzsYjpWca53utFWyW7ZZUc1awxQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=react&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=).

### EDIT

Should have read the code more closely.

The reason you need a function there is because its a context consumer. The `user` gets injected via the context provider and the only way for it to do that is for you to give it a function to pass arguments to.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the function decorators. I am still wondering why do we need to use the function in the line I have mentioned before, I thought as well that we already have the user in the props. But, if I remove the function and just leave the ```<Component {...props}  />```  the sandbox example crushes.

Comment: @Leff can you provide a link?

Comment: @Leff see my updated answer. Sorry it took so long to get back to your question, but I had to solve actual work problems instead of stack overflow problems.